# How to control foam in the modifier panel?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I was recently trying to create an ocean scene and searched up some tutorials, there were lots using a lot of node setups but after a long walk I found a ways to generate foam from the modifier panel, so I gave it a try:[image]

There's not much control given in the modifier's panel and mostly the render looks dull but some part look pretty good like the one encircled. Is there some way to control this more accurately?

Comment: Related: http://www.blendernation.com/2016/01/21/blender-2-7x-jumping-the-shark-qa/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Paint Cycles - How do you make waves caused by an object to turn white?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60844/dynamic-paint-cycles-how-do-you-make-waves-caused-by-an-object-to-turn-white)