# Dynamic Paint Cycles - How do you make waves caused by an object to turn white?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, dynamic-paint

So I am trying to simulate a motorboat using a sphere in Blender Cycles using dynamic paint. So the sphere goes across the water and causes waves but I want the waves to slightly turn a whitish color because if you have ever seen a motor boat go over waves in real life there is always a trail of white waves behind it.

My waves so far:
[image]

What I want the waves to look like: 
[image]

Node Set Up for first image: 
[image]

When I tried to apply the answer I got this as my result:
[image]

Blender File:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Geometry Input - Pointiness

You might want to experiment with the Geometry Input and try out Pointiness to mix the whitecaps with the water.

[image]

## Update

1. The order of the Shader inputs is important. If white becomes the dominant color, the inputs on the Mix Shader need to be swapped.
2. The black value in the color ramp should start at 0.5 or above. We want to preserve the water material and only add the whitecap material to the pointy parts of the mesh.

**If an answer was helpful please consider marking it accepted**

Here's your updated blend file:

[image]

Comment: yes... +1 (even if we are not supposed to say +1). Or a combination with the Z, eventually.

Comment: Hey I edited this question by adding my node set up picture, what would I change in the node set up for your solution?

Comment: @AustinH.  Your current material is the blue color in my setup, so you would have to create a second material for the whitecaps. The rest should be pretty much the same. Mix them together with the pointiness node and the color ramp as the factor.

Comment: I tried mixing them but it made it completely white.

Comment: Uhm.. yeah. Pics or it didn't happen ;-)

Comment: Or maybe uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ would be even better.

Comment: Okay check the repost, there is a pic and there is the blend file.

Comment: 1. You need to swap Mix Shader inputs. Your material should go in the upper, white into the lower. Just like in my setup. 2. The black value for the color ramp should start at 0.5 or above. Below 0.5 it influences your material as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a color depending on the Z value... but I am not sure this is enough to get the effect you want.

So this is not a real answer (I think) but more a clue to do it better.

However, this can be merged/combined with other colors/textures (noise, etc.) and shaders, of course :

[image]