# How to recreate foam when sea waves impact on surface

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I would like to recreate foam when my sea waves impact and flow through the texture of my geometry: 
[image]

As you can see the flow recreates a nice interaction but still it does not look completely real. 
You can find here the doc: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0ezgnimw45pwq2/doc.%20forum.blend?dl=0

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: See my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60844/dynamic-paint-cycles-how-do-you-make-waves-caused-by-an-object-to-turn-white/60853#60853

Comment: Thank you @metaphor_set I will try to follow your instructions.

Comment: @metaphor_set is there by any chance a way to do this in Blender Render and not in Cycles? For some reason this rendering tool works better for me..

Comment: Not that I know of, I'm afraid. Blender Internal has no Pointiness in the Geometry Node. There might be other methods, but this one is the only one I've ever tried.